# Grade Calculator Using Arrays

Tags: java, arrays

We're writing a program called GradeBook and it allows the user to enter student data such as name, and score of different grade items. GradeBook provide option compute grade for each student and to plot the class grade distribution. The user can always go back and add more student data. The maximum number of students it supports is 200 and the maximum number of grade items in a category is 10. For example, it only supports up to 10 quizzes, 10 exams, and 10 homework assignments.

An example of the data entering would be something like this:

Joe W. Smith: e100 e95 e87 q10 q10 q8 h10 h10 h10

Michael Brown: q10 q10 h7 h10 h9 h10 e80

To display the students grades and statistics we're supposed to use System.out.printf.

Here is another example of what the final output should be.

```
 Name     Exam Exam Exam Quiz Quiz Quiz HWork HWork HWork Grade

 Danny Devito 100.0  80.0 90.0 10.0 10.0 0.0 10.0 5.0 10.0 84.0

 Joe Smith 85.0 90.0 100.0 10.0 10.0 5.0 0.0 10.0 5.0      81.7

 Will Smith 60.0 100.0 90.0 10.0 10.0 8.0 10.0 0.0 10.0    82.0
```

This final example is supposed to be lined up better and alligned by the decimals so it looks neat and clean but I'm unsure on how to do that.

```
  import java.util.Scanner;
```

public class GradeCalcWithArrays { /*
                                     * Logan Wegner The purpose is to calculate
                                     * entered grades
                                     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {

```
    Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);

    boolean done = false;
    boolean quit = false;
    int choice = 0;

    int studentcounter = 0;

    int[] examstats = new int[3]; /*
                                 * Array created to store the information
                                 * entered for exams
                                 */
    int[] quizstats = new int[3]; /*
                                 * Array created to store the information
                                 * entered for quizzes
                                 */
    int[] homeworkstats = new int[3]; /*
                                     * Array created to store the
                                     * information entered for homework
                                     */

    String[] studentnames = new String[200]; /*
                                             * Array created to store the
                                             * student name information
                                             * entered
                                             */

    System.out.println("Welcome to GradeBook!");
    System.out.println("Please provide grade item details");

    System.out.print("Exams    (number, points, weight):");

    examstats[0] = s.nextInt(); // inputs exam number
    examstats[1] = s.nextInt(); // inputs exam points
    examstats[2] = s.nextInt(); // inputs exam weight

    System.out.print("Quizzes     (number, points, weight):");

    quizstats[0] = s.nextInt(); // inputs quiz number
    quizstats[1] = s.nextInt(); // inputs quiz points
    quizstats[2] = s.nextInt(); // inputs quiz weight

    System.out.print("Homework    (number, points, weight):");

    homeworkstats[0] = s.nextInt(); // inputs homework number
    homeworkstats[1] = s.nextInt(); // inputs homework points
    homeworkstats[2] = s.nextInt(); // inputs homework weight

    System.out.println("--------------------");

    do {
        System.out.println("What would you like to do?");
        System.out.println("    1 Add student data");
        System.out.println("    2 Display student grades & statistics");
        System.out.println("    3 Plot grade distribution");
        System.out.println("    4 Quit");
        System.out.print("Your choice:");
        choice = s.nextInt(); /*
                             * Choice will determine what the next course of
                             * action will be with the program
                             */

        if (choice == 1) {
            System.out.println("Enter student data:");
            for (int i = 0; i <= 200; i++) {
                studentcounter = studentcounter + 1;
                System.out.print("Data>");
                studentnames[i] = s.nextLine();

                if (studentnames[i].equals("done")) {
                    break;
                }
            }
        }

        if (choice == 2) {

        }

        if (choice == 3) {

        }

        if (choice == 4) {
            quit = true;
            System.out.println("Good bye!");
        }

    } while (quit == false);

}

 }
```

The biggest part I'm stuck on is just being able to enter the data and having it be put in strings and arrays. I'm unsure on how to take the data entered by using e100 q100 h100 because they can be mixed up and out of order. I'd really really really appreciate some help with this. Thanks in advance guys.

Answer (score 0):

Try to isolate your question to the things you're actually confused on. Usually this leads to you figuring out what you need to do.

It looks like you're really just unsure of how to separate the `exam`, `quiz`, and `homework` strings into 3 separate arrays because they're not in any order. Well, to separate them, they must have differences. What's the difference between the three types of strings?

All 3 types of string inputs can have some number between 0 and 100 attached to a letter: 'e', 'q', or 'h'. So the only difference is the first letter of each string. Thus, to separate all of the various strings into separate arrays, you check what the first letter is and place it accordingly into it's corresponding array.

Now you're finally at a point where you need to code: how do you programatically separate strings based on their first letter?

Well, you have `if` statements and I'm sure you can figure out how to get the first character of a string.

Laid out in words (aka pseudocode):

```
String s;
Char c;

c = //get the first letter of string 's'. Figure this out with a simple google search.

if (c == 'e') 
{
    //Add the string after the first character in string s to the Exam array
    //NOTE: You have int arrays, so you will need to convert the string to an int
    //      before adding it to the array.
}
else if (c == 'q')
{
    //Same as above with Quiz array
} 
else if ...
{
    //... you should be able to finish this!
}
```

This should get you started on your project. Try to emulate the thought process that's detailed above for the rest of your assignment and you'll quickly find out that every problem you encounter at a beginner level has been solved before; you just need to find out what specifically your problem is in terms of programming.

Comment: Thank you for the help. That was definitely 90% of my question. I think I know what you mean by instead of doing the s.firstLetter thing. Are you saying I should use split to pick out the e's and then I'll be able to input the different scores into the right arrays? Or should I be trying to use substring to find the e's and then after that input my grades in the right arrays?

Comment: @Daniel Whatever makes the most sense to you. You can do it in a bunch of different ways. I don't want to tell you exactly how to do it, but if you read the code I posted above you can analyze it and figure out my thought process and intentions (mainly through the `if` blocks).

Comment: The example that is given is 'Joe Smith: e100 e80 e90 q10 q10 q0 h10  h5 h10' To start off J is the first character of the sequence and there are more than one e, q, and h. The way you explained how to go about this it only takes on character correct? I'm confused as to how I'm going to find the 3 e's or however many there will be, and then get all their values into an array.

Comment: @Daniel Ah, okay. You need to do both things you said then. Look for a pattern in each input and split the string accordingly. What I would do is split the string by a semicolon so you have two strings, the name and then the rest of the string: ' e100 q100' etc. Use the name string however you need to and then split the second string by spaces, so you'll have 'e100', 'q100', etc. Then do what I said in the answer with those strings. You will have to loop over the strings and add each one to its corresponding array.

Comment: Thanks for all the help so far Matthew. I've gotten everything working now besides the part where I convert the string to an int before adding it to the array. Can you give me some insight on how to do this please?

Comment: @Daniel Search "how to convert a string to an int java" on google. :P

Comment: `for (int i = 0; i <= 200; i++) {
     System.out.print("Data>");
     String dataentry = s.nextLine();

     String[] firstsplit = dataentry.split(":");
     String[] secondsplit = firstsplit[1].split(" ");

     for (int j = 0; j <= 200; j++) {

      String c;

      c = secondsplit[j].substring(0 , 1);` Hey matthew, I'm still having trouble with my program. For some reason when I try to run it now there is an error where I declare my secondstring array and split it. Have any insight on this?

Comment: @Daniel I subtly mentioned it earlier but you probably missed it ;) The 2nd string in `firstsplit` (the e100 e95 e85 etc) actually starts with a space, so when `firstsplit` is split by a space, the first value in the corresponding array is an empty string. When you try to access the first character in an empty string, you get a runtime error. So you can do one of two things: 1. Trim the string, removing leading/trailing whitespaces with String.trim(). so you'd just `.trim()` `firststring` in the `secondsplit` declaration like so: `String secondsplit[] = (firstsplit.trim()).split(" ");`

Comment: or if for some reason you're not allowed to use the `.trim()` method (some professors are like this, I know) then you can just test if it's empty before setting the value of `c`: `if (!secondsplit[j].isEmpty()) { //...blahblahblah }`

Also, you're trying to access memory you're not sure is going to be there by using a `for loop` from `1 to 200`. The smarter way to do this is either go from `1` to `j <= firstsplit[1].length()` or just use a `for each` loop: `for (String c: secondsplit) { //...do stuff with String c }`